# Store key,value pair in YAML and use to populate a Rails form :collection?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, refactoring

How would one store a list of languages with there language code into a yaml and popuplate a :collection in rails form with?  I now have below example but fails, any suggestions on what would be best option to tackle this problem?

**Application.yml:**

```
development:
  language:     [['English', 'en'], ['French', 'fr']]

production:
  language:     [['English', 'en']
```

**In rails form:**

```
= f.input :locale, :collection => APP_CONFIG['languages']
```

Comment: Can you describe your failure?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For some reason I never thought of storing data structures more complicated than a string in my i18n YAML files, but your question gave me food for thought to change my ways in this case, so thank you very much (and +1)!

I originally had a method similar to @Sachin R's solution in my `ApplicationHelper` (though not related to a particular Rails environment) like this:

**app/helpers/application_helper.rb**

```
def locale_language_labels
  [
    { label: t('layouts.locale_selector.en'), locale: 'en' },
    { label: t('layouts.locale_selector.it'), locale: 'it' },
    { label: t('layouts.locale_selector.ja'), locale: 'ja' }
  ]
end
```

which pulled out the values below (depending on the locale, of course):

**config/locales/layouts/layouts_en.yml**

```
en:
  layouts:
    locale_selector:
      en: English
      it: Italiano (Italian)
      ja: 日本語 (Japanese)
```

My locale selector (Twitter Bootstrap formatted) would then populate those values like this:

**app/views/layouts/_locale_selector.html.haml**

```
%li#fat-menu.dropdown
  %a.dropdown-toggle{"data-toggle" => "dropdown", href: "#"}
    %i.icon-globe
    = t('.language')
    %b.caret
  %ul.dropdown-menu
    - locale_language_labels.each do |language|
      %li
        = link_to language[:label],
                  controller: controller,
                  action: action,
                  set_locale: language[:locale],
                  page: page
```

Now, I've gotten rid of the `locale_language_labels` method and put my locale selector languages in a hash in the YAML file, which may be a good candidate for your question.  My code now looks like the following:

**config/locales/layouts/layouts_en.yml**

```
en:
  layouts:
    locale_selector:
      language: Language
      language_labels: { en: English,
                         it: Italiano (Italian),
                         ja: 日本語 (Japanese) }
```

**app/views/layouts/_locale_selector.html.haml**

```
%li#fat-menu.dropdown
  %a.dropdown-toggle{"data-toggle" => "dropdown", href: "#"}
    %i.icon-globe
    = t('.language')
    %b.caret
  %ul.dropdown-menu
    - t('.language_labels').each_pair do |locale, label|
      %li
        = link_to label,
                  controller: controller,
                  action: action,
                  set_locale: locale,
                  page: page
```

Pairing the language label with the locale in the YAML file makes much more sense to me since they are a tightly coupled pair, and it doesn't seem natural now to have one half defined in YAML and another in a helper.

Comment: your reaction inspired me on how to tackle this problem thanks for the informative writeup!

Comment: Glad to have helped, and thanks to you again for the question.  If you're able to share how you actually solved your problem, please add an edit to your question!

Answer (score 1):

create a helper method in some application hepler file

```
def getLangCollection()
    if Rails.env == 'development'
     language = [['English', 'en'], ['French', 'fr']]
    elsif Rails.env == 'production'
     language = [['English', 'en']
    else
     language = [['English', 'en']
    return language
end
```

Comment: yes but I would like to store it in /config/application.yml since thats the main location for these kind of things. to have everything in 1 place, I would also no longer need the rails environment check since the APP_CONFIG['languages'] would already contain the correct key value pairs

Comment: yes ok, but its not solution to question, +1 it thought appreciate your feedback, but still looking for way to do inside yaml